# How to update field value from another field in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

How to dublicate 'url' values, if it is not empty, for the same 'id' but another 'lang'

| id | lang | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | cat-url |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 1 | dog-url |
| 2 | 2 |  |

Result should be

| id | lang | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | cat-url |
| 1 | 2 | cat-url |
| 2 | 1 | dog-url |
| 2 | 2 | dog-url |

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a tricky way with user defined variables

Or if you have MySQL 8 use can use a window function

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   `d` INTEGER,
>   `lang` INTEGER,
>   `url` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   (`d`, `lang`, `url`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', 'cat-url'),
>   ('1', '2', NULL),
>     ('1', '2', NULL),
>   ('2', '1', 'dog-url'),
>   ('2', '2',NULL);
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE tab1
> SET `url` = (@url := COALESCE(`url`, @url))
> ORDER BY `d`;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab1
> ```
>
> ```
>  d | lang | url    
> -: | ---: | :------
>  1 |    1 | cat-url
>  1 |    2 | cat-url
>  1 |    2 | cat-url
>  2 |    1 | dog-url
>  2 |    2 | dog-url
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab2 (
>   `d` INTEGER,
>   `lang` INTEGER,
>   `url` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab2
>   (`d`, `lang`, `url`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', 'cat-url'),
>   ('1', '2', NULL),
>     ('1', '2', NULL),
>   ('2', '1', 'dog-url'),
>   ('2', '2',NULL);
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE tab2
> INNER JOIN
> (SELECT d, FIRST_VALUE(`url`) OVER(PARTITION BY `d` ORDER BY `lang`) as url FROM tab2) t1
> SET tab2.`url` = t1.`url`
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab2
> ```
>
> ```
>  d | lang | url    
> -: | ---: | :------
>  1 |    1 | cat-url
>  1 |    2 | cat-url
>  1 |    2 | cat-url
>  2 |    1 | cat-url
>  2 |    2 | cat-url
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b6ed117219c3cd4109729aa6efa3559)*